# Inclusion-Exclusion Lower Bound

Tags: probability, statistics, inclusion-exclusion

Suppose that 80% of families own a DVD player and that 70% of families that own a computer. What is the range of possible percentages of families that own both?

I was able to see that the highest possible percentage of families that own both was 70%, since only 70% of families own a computer. However, I guessed the lower bound of the range by adding both percentages to get 80%+70% = 150% and subtracting 100% from it since it is impossible for over 100% of families to own both to get 50% of families that own both, which happened to be correct. Can someone please explain if this is the correct way to obtain the lower end of the range, and if so, why? Also, is there a general formula for the lower bound if the percentages are x% and y%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can very simply be determined by a line diagram.

Draw a line representing $100\%$ between $A$ and $B$

For maximum % owning both, draw the lines for both families from $A$ to $B$

$0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0 $ 100% line
$0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\quad$ A 80%
$0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\quad$ B 70%
Overlap 70%

- For minimum % owning both, draw the lines for the two  from *opposite* sides.The overlap now is minimum % owning both

$0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0 $ 100% line
$0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\quad\quad$ A 80%
$\quad\quad0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0
\;\;\,$ B 70%
Overlap 50%

Comment: Is it possible for you to elaborate? I don't quite follow.

Comment: Diagram added. Should be clear !

Comment: Similar idea using venn diagrams. Start with two circles tangential to each other. Now the total is at $150\%$. Now move the right circle to the left until we have the minimum overlap which has the total at $100\%$. Next you can continue to move the circle and have it fully inside the left circle which gives you max overlap at $70\%$.

Comment: @sku: True, but for such cases, I brlieve a "line" diagram is simpler and clearer.

Comment: @dphil1: There is no reaction from your side ! If the answer is now clear, why don't you  close the question by ticking it.

Comment: @trueblueanil thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Glad to be of help ! Do keep the concept of the "line" diagram in mind. Often I find it useful in even more complex problems.